# How do i tar directories that do not contain at least one file accesed in the last month using shell

Tags: bash, shell

Like consider the below, directory path,

```
./file1
./dirA
 ./dirA/dirC
  ./dirA/dirC/file4
  ./dirA/dirC/file5
  ./dirA/dirC/dirD
   ./dirA/dirC/dirD/file8
   ./dirA/dirC/dirD/file6
   ./dirA/dirC/dirD/file7
 ./dirA/dirE
  ./dirA/dirE/file9
 ./dirA/file2
 ./dirA/file3
./dirB
 ./dirB/file10
  ./dirB/dirF
   ./dirB/dirF/file11
   ./dirB/dirF/file12
   ./dirB/dirF/dirG
    ./dirB/dirF/dirG/file13
```

The only files that have been used are  accessed in the past month are file10 and file6.

Hence, the new structre will be like,

```
./file1
./dirA
 ./dirA/dirC
  ./dirA/dirC/file4
  ./dirA/dirC/file5
  ./dirA/dirC/dirD
   ./dirA/dirC/dirD/file8
   ./dirA/dirC/dirD/file6
   ./dirA/dirC/dirD/file7
 ./dirA/dirE.tgz
 ./dirA/file2
 ./dirA/file3
./dirB
 ./dirB/file10
  ./dirB/dirF.tgz
```

I did try the below script , it's working i just wanted to see  if there could be a simple and better way of doing it.

```
for dir in `find . -type f -atime +30 -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq`; do test `find $dir -type f -atime -30 -print -quit` || tar -czvf $dir.tgz --remove-files $dir; done
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Running this should do the job:

```
find . -type f -atime +30 -exec tar -czvf files.tgz {} +;
```

Comment: @user8129204 Do mark this as correct if this solves your problem, to help others seeking something similar.

Comment: I assume that `files.tgz` is overwritten when upper limit on argument length is reached.

Comment: won't be nitpicking but question is about directories